# How to exclude intra-project dependency when running maven dependency:go-offline

Tags: maven

I have a multi-module project where I want to download all dependencies for offline use. I do this using the `mvn dependency:go-offline` goal. In the project, there is one module X that depends on another module Y. Since the `dependency:go-offline` command does not build the modules, there is an error when building X that the dependency Y is not found:

```
$ mvn dependency:go-offline -Dmaven.artifact.threads=30

 Failure to find se.cust.id:Y:jar:1.2.3-SNAPSHOT in https://mvn.com.com/repository/com-snapshots/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of com-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced
```

I've tried to make Maven ignore this dependency by running

```
$ mvn dependency:go-offline -DexcludeArtifactIds=Y
```

But this results in the same error. What is the proper way of excluding dependencies here?

Answer (score 4):

Adding `maven-dependency-plugin` to the parent `pom.xml` worked for me

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2</version>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran across the problem while encapsulating a maven build with a Dockerfile (like so: http://whitfin.io/speeding-up-maven-docker-builds/)

My workaround so far is to just let the dependency-fetch fail, which looks like this in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN mvn -B dependency:go-offline -DexcludeGroupIds=my.company || true
```

I can tell that the `-DexcludeGroupIds` doesn't work because I get an error:

```
Failure to find my.company:subproject-built-here:jar:1-SNAPSHOT in http://packages.confluent.io/maven/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until...
```

Enough of the dependencies are downloaded and cached that I still see a speedup later on, but I'd prefer to prevent the error rather than ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem as well, and my approach was to run `mvn test-compile` to force the dependency downloads (or at least most of them). It's not ideal since it'll process more steps of the project lifecycle than are needed, but assuming your code compiles, you should get largely the same result in the end.

It appears that this missing feature has been an open issue for some time now. See these links:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-568
- https://github.com/apache/maven-dependency-plugin/pull/2 (pull request #2!)
- https://github.com/apache/maven-dependency-plugin/pull/135